# Copying a function from a package in Julia

Tags: function, copy, julia

DISCLAIMER: I am aware that the following is extremely bad practice. I just need a quick-fix for debugging purposes.

I am trying to run a Julia package that is `using` both JuMP.jl and LightXML.jl.

I get the following error:

`WARNING: both JuMP and LightXML export "name"; uses of it in module JEMSS must be qualified`

LightXML is added first, so I'd like to make a copy of `name`, then let JuMP override.

What is the syntax to do this?

The `name` function consists of:

```
name(::LightXML.XMLElement)
name(::LightXML.XMLNode)
name(::LightXML.XMLAttr)
```

Comment: Are you aware this warning is only about the code you are going to write? This does not affect the packages themselves as their namespaces are exclusive. You can use them together without any problem except if you want to use `name` *in your code* you write `JuMP.name` when you want to use the one in `JuMP` and `LightXML.name` when you want to use the one in `LightXML`. I just wanted to point these out although what you ask is quite possible.

Comment: Ahh, this worked. Thank you so much! Just for interest though, how would you actually copy such a function?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by copying. Do you just want `name` in `LightXML`  to have a different name than `name` so you can refer to it without any collusion?

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean exactly, e.g. `name2 = ...`, where `name2` can be used like `LightXML.name` for all the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, I should write that the warning tells you that if you want to use `name` in your code, you should specify which module's `name` you want to use. You do this by *qualify*ing it with the module/package name such as `LightXML.name` or `JuMP.name`.

If you want to create an *alias* for, say, `LightXML.name`, this is also possible.

```
using LightXML

# make `name2` be an alias for `LightXML.name`
const name2 = LightXML.name # `name2` refers to `LightXML.name` but `LightXML.name` still exists

using JuMP
using JuMP: name # tell the compiler `name` without qualifiers refer to `JuMP.name` so you do not have to qualify it
```

This actually does not give change the name of `LightXML.name` but rather create an *alias* for `LightXML.name`. After this, you can write `name2` instead of `LightXML.name` or still use `LightXML.name` as is.

Note that `const` is an important detail here otherwise whenever you use `name2` Julia will have to look it up whether what `name2` refers has changed and this will degrade performance.

The other thing to note is that if you want to use `name` without qualifiers to refer to `JuMP.name`, you write `using JuMP: name` to indicate to the compiler which `name` should  be used (since there are still two `name`s). You should, however, do this *before* using `name` without any qualifier in your code.

The following therefore will *not* work.

```
julia> using LightXML
julia> name             # we used `name` here to refer to `LightXML.name `
julia> using JuMP       # this will give you the same warning in your question
julia> using JuMP: name # this will give you a warning and be **ignored**

# `name` continues to refer to `LightXML.name` rather than `JuMP.name`
```